# send mail by trigger when a new row inserted/updated into a table

Tags: triggers

I have already created a update trigger on a table, which inserts a value into third table after subtraction. Now I want that whenever a new value is get inserted into table three it sends a mail for that insertion. Can anybody help..please?????

Answer (score 0):

Depends on which system you are using.

On postgres I did this by writing a trigger in Perl, loading Perl's mail module, and just sending it out.

On MS SQL Server, you execute master.xp_sendmail, as in this link (the first hit on Google) http://www.datasprings.com/resources/articles-information/creating-email-triggers-in-sql-server-2005

What they all have in common is that most db servers are not email servers, so you have to invoke some other system to send it out.  Each platform is different in how you do that.

Comment: In SQL 2005 you would be better off using DBMail.  Better than the old xp_sendmail.